# I save the data using button but how to save using <a href=""> in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my code for button that save data successfully ..

```
<input class="es_textbox_button" name="es_txt_button_pg" id="es_txt_button_pg" onClick="return es_submit_pages('.$url.')" value="'.__('Subscribe', 'email-subscribers').'" type="button">
```

[image]

I want to add email using mail icon in text field how to give the link in textfiled ..plzz give any solution ...

Comment: use like this tag.....<a href='which link you want'><img></a>

Comment: visit this http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-checkboxes-radios

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
<input type="image" 
       class="es_textbox_button" 
       name="es_txt_button_pg" 
       id="es_txt_button_pg" 
       value="'.__('Subscribe', 'email-subscribers').'"
       onClick="return es_submit_pages('.$url.')" 
       src="images/image.png" />
```